# How can I disable Lumension Sanctuary

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, malware

I'm an administrator on my computer but I can't work out how to uninstall/disable Lumension Sanctuary. There is no Uninstall button in the uninstall programs list.

I've disabled the service (Sanctuary command and control) but it's had no effect.

Any ideas?

I'm on Windows XP BTW.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is this runs in the kernel as a device driver.  You'll need to boot into safe mode and disable the device, then you can read/write to your USB stick.  If they set it up correctly, you won't be able to get on the network because it will require the device (Sanctuary) is running for you to join your domain.  So, boot into safe mode, disable the device, do your reading/writing, then boot back into normal mode with Sanctuary running and get back on your domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a lot easier than that guys.

If you just want to uninstall it:

1. Go to regedit
2. Navigate to the following node:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE  
   |--SOFTWARE
      |--Microsoft 
         |--Windows 
            |--CurrentVersion 
               |--Uninstall
   ```
3. Search for Lumension or Sanctuary (depending on your flavour).
4. Change the following values to '0':

   - NoRepair
   - NoRemove
   - NoModify

That's us finished with regedit.

1. Go to "Add and Remove Programs."
2. You'll find the Sanctuary Management Console listed (if you installed it), and the Sanctuary client. They will now have the option to 'remove'.
3. Restart your machine.
4. Job done.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work if client hardening is enabled from the server. You will also need to issue a maintenance ticket from the server.

If you are a customer and need help removing the agent, please seek further technical advice from Lumension support - support@lumension.com